# Why is ConcurrentModificationException not thrown after an unsafe operation, but after the whole forEach loop?

Tags: lambda, java-8, java-stream

Normally, a ConcurrentModificationException is thrown immediately when a modification is made while an iteration is in progress.

However, With the stream API's forEachOrdered method, the Exception is not thrown after each modification. Instead, the modification can be made successfully during iteration, and eventually an exception is thrown after the whole operation is done. Can someone explain to me that how this happens?

The code below is generating 3 random numbers that are ranged from -0.5 to 0.5. It then filter out the negative values.

```
        HashMap<Integer, Double> positiveNegative = new HashMap<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            double value =Math.random() - 0.5;
            positiveNegative.put(i, value);
        }

        System.out.println(positiveNegative);

        //filter out the negative value
        positiveNegative.entrySet().stream()
                .filter((entry) -> (entry.getValue() < 0))
                .forEachOrdered(entry -> {
                    System.out.println(entry);
                    positiveNegative.remove(entry.getKey());
                    System.out.println(positiveNegative);
                });

        System.out.println(positiveNegative);
```

```
{0=-0.38785299800912576, 1=-0.11085161629013052, 2=-0.3516129030809366}
0=-0.38785299800912576
{1=-0.11085161629013052, 2=-0.3516129030809366}
1=-0.11085161629013052
{2=-0.3516129030809366}
2=-0.3516129030809366
{}

Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.base/java.util.HashMap$EntrySpliterator.forEachRemaining(HashMap.java:1751)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:150)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:173)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachOrdered(ReferencePipeline.java:502)
    at Solution.main(Solution.java:51)
```

Comment: I'm getting the exception earlier. I guess it's an implementation detail that depends on the specific Java version.

Comment: Instead of modifying the collection while you're trying to iterate upon the same, a better implementation could be `System.out.println("Initial entries: " + positiveNegative); positiveNegative.entrySet().removeIf(entry -> entry.getValue() < 0); System.out.println("Final entries: " + positiveNegative);`

Comment: @Naman or even simpler `positiveNegative.values().removeIf(v -> v < 0);`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/HashMap.html) says:

> Note that the fail-fast behavior of an iterator cannot be guaranteed as it is, generally speaking, impossible to make any hard guarantees in the presence of unsynchronized concurrent modification. Fail-fast iterators throw `ConcurrentModificationException` on a best-effort basis. Therefore, it would be wrong to write a program that depended on this exception for its correctness: *the fail-fast behavior of iterators should be used only to detect bugs.*

There’s no concurrency involved in your example, but the point remains; this feature is only meant to detect bugs, not to give you a guarantee about whether or when the exception is thrown. To detect the bug, it is sufficient *if* the exception is thrown, even if only at the end of the iteration.

In case of the `hasNext()` and `next()` methods of an `Iterator`, there is no control over the caller. The caller is not required to iterate to the end of the collection, in other words, every method call could be the last one, before the `Iterator` gets abandoned. So these methods can not postpone the check.

In contrast, the `forEachRemaining` methods of `Iterator` and `Spliterator` are in control of the iteration loop and know when they will exit, hence, can omit checking in every iteration and perform a single check at the end, assuming that we have a specialized implementation, rather than the `default` method which has no choice but to call the single element iteration methods repeatedly.

As you can see in the stacktrace, the `forEachOrdered` Stream operation ends up at `HashMap$EntrySpliterator.forEachRemaining`, a specialized implementation which takes that opportunity. The obvious reason is performance, as you don’t want to waste CPU cycles for testing a condition in each iteration that ought to be `false` anyway, when the contract allows to do it once at the end (if we deduce a requirement from a *best-effort* basis contract at all).

Comment: Wow, thanks a lot. That’s a well informed answer to the question